# How do I apply a ColorDataFunction[] to a grayscale image?

Tags: color, image, performance-tuning

Suppose I have a 2D array `im` of real values between 0 and 1, representing a grayscale image. I can turn `im` into an image very efficiently with `Image[im]` (in fact, on my machine, `AbsoluteTiming@Image[im]` returns `0.` for a 1920 by 1080 array). I would like to colorize `im` by applying a `ColorDataFunction`, for example, `ColorData["AvocadoColors"]`, to each entry of `im`. My first thought was to use `Image@Map[ColorData["AvocadoColors"], im, {2}]`, but this is unreasonably expensive, taking nearly a minute for a 1920 by 1080 array. What is a more efficient way to produce the same output?

Comment: `Colorize[im, ColorFunction->"AvocadoColors"]`?

Comment: @kguler Remember to `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

Comment: @kguler I just came back to post that, that's the correct solution. Why don't you post it?

Comment: @kguler Did you mean `Colorize[Image[im], ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]`? When I execute your code, I'm told that `Colorize` is `Expecting an integer matrix or an image instead of {<<1>>}`.

Comment: David, yes. @Kuba, not sure if it is needed here.

Comment: @Szabolcs, just posted the comment as answer. Your deleted answer seems to be faster on a few example images i tried.

Comment: @kguler Yes, agree, it was rather comment for visitors. This is devil's option ;)

Comment: @MrWizard I understood this question as asking about how to create an `Image` object.  The duplicate doesn't show this.

Comment: @Szabolcs Even if it isn't addressing precisely the same question, the duplicate does give a solution to my problem (which is faster than all the answers below, to boot). I'm happy with this being marked as duplicate.

Comment: @DavidZhang If you're happy with that then it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
im = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial"}];

Colorize[im, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] // Timing // First
(* 0.093750 *)
```

versus

```
ImageApply[List @@ ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#] &, im] // Timing // First
(* 0.265625 *)

ImageApply[List @@ Blend["AvocadoColors", #] &, im] // Timing // First (thanks: @Kuba *)
(* 0.109375 *)
```

For a larger image:

```
imlarge = Image[ RandomReal[1, {1080, 1920}]];

f1 = Colorize[#, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &;
f2 = Image@Raster[ImageData[#, DataReversed -> True], ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] &;
f3 = ImageApply[List @@ Blend["AvocadoColors", #] &, #] &;

First[Timing@#[imlarge]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
{2.234375, 2.140625, 3.093750}
```

Comment: Is this really the fastest it can be done? I was hoping, since `Image[im]` is so fast, that I might be able to apply a `ColorDataFunction` in a comparable amount of time. For me, these all take several seconds for a 1920 by 1080 image.

Comment: @DavidZhang, i am sure answers with faster methods will trickle in if you wait a few hours/days.

Answer (score 2):

[`Raster`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster.html) will be helpful, as it has the [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) option and it can be directly converted back to an `Image`.

Let `img` be a grayscale image:

```
img = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"]

Image@Raster[ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note: this is just an idea that has the advantage of brevity and simplicity.  I haven't tested performance.

Comment: Undeleted on request.  kguler's answer is the "standard" way though.