# Intensity variation of image as ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to color code the brightness values of an image (8bit, gray scale, 1600*1200 pixels).
Each pixel should be color coded according to its brightness value using a dedicated color table.

An example image can be downloaded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlRXR.png).

The brightness histogram is:

```
Histogram[Flatten@ImageData@image, {1/256}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"# of Pixels", ""}, {"Brightness", ""}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
  FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, 
  ImageSize -> 2000, ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 50}}]
```

So most of the brightness values are around 0.045.

[image]

I tested `ListContourPlot` but it is extremely slow (`AbsoluteTiming` gives 91 sec).

```
colTable = {{Black}, 
   Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 0.2, 1, 0.1}]}; 
colTable = Flatten[colTable]

ListContourPlot[ImageData@image, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), Contours -> 10]
```

How can I improve the contrast of the color coded image?

Do you know an other or faster solution?

[image]

Comment: The code you used to make the `ListContourPlot`?

Comment: Have you looked at `Colorize[]`?

Comment: Is the image in the post the same as the link?

Comment: @Young: The image in the link corresponds to the `image` in the code.

Comment: @mrz - I don't get the same result when I run your code:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/12N5E.png

Comment: @JasonB: I had mistake, now it should be the same ...

Comment: But that last image looked more interesting - how did you get it?

Comment: Related: [21482](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21482)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

New and fast (4 seconds) way to achieve plot and scale.

```
colTable = {{Black}, Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 0.2, 1, 0.1}]};
colTable = Flatten[colTable];

ArrayPlot[ImageData[imageOrg], ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &),
          PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]

---

Other methods:

[`Colorize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Colorize.html)

```
Colorize[imageOrg, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &),
         ColorFunctionScaling -> False] //Timing
```

> 2.15281

[image]

[How do I apply a ColorDataFunction[] to a grayscale image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75257/how-do-i-apply-a-colordatafunction-to-a-grayscale-image)

---

```
Image@Raster[ImageData[imageOrg, DataReversed -> True],
             ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)] // Timing
```

> 2.19961

[image]

Comment: Thank you ... this is very fast, but if I use my color table the output of your code is different than my image above, why? Is it possible to use `Colorize` with a legend showing which color corresponds to which brightness?

Comment: @mrz I'm unable to replicate your histogram or plot even when I run your code

Comment: Now it should work. When I use `Image@Raster[ImageData[image, DataReversed -> True], 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)]` I get a relatively nice image.

Comment: @mrz Seems just as fast

Comment: Very good ... is there a way to plot beside the image a legend showing which color corresponds to which brightness?

Comment: @mrz found a new way that's fast and adds the scale easily

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83967).

Comment: @J. M.: Your link is extremely helpful, I will try to adapt it to my question ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another color table:

```
colTable = 
 Flatten@{Table[Black, {x, 0, 12, 1}], 
   Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/10, 1, 1/10}], 
   Table[Black, {x, 24, 256, 1}]}

ArrayPlot[ImageData[image], ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]

```
Colorize[image, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)]
```

[image]